# delete route in flask application does not work

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

form:

```
<form style="display:inline-block;"  action="/venues/{{venue.id}}" method="DELETE">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
</form>
```

app.py:

```
@app.route('/venues/<venue_id>', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_venue(venue_id):
  try:
    venue = Venue.query.get(venue_id)
    db.session.delete(venue)
    db.session.commit()
  except:
    db.session.rollback()
  finally:
    db.session.close()
  return redirect(url_for('venues'))
```

when I hit submit nothing happens. I tried to redirect only and it's still the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114156/why-are-there-are-no-put-and-delete-methods-on-html-forms

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker Thanks